# Method 'POST' error 419 on local server Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, csrf

When i submit a post form on my page it doesn't work, it redirects me on the action route with error 419, this is an example of my form:

```
<form action="{{route('client.login')}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('POST')
                    <h4 class="login-title">Login</h4>
                    <div class="login-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-12 mb--20">
                                <label>Email*</label>
                                <input class="mb-0" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 mb--20">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input class="mb-0" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" name="password"
                                value="{{ old('password') }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black me-3">Login</button>
                                    <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" class="mb-0 me-1">
                                        <label for="remember" class="mb-0 font-weight-400">Ricordami</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                <p><a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="pass-lost mt-3">Password dimenticata?</a></p>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I've checked the csrf tokens, and they match.
I've the exact same code on my server-side files and they work perfectly, but doesn't work on my local server.
I can't find anywhere the log of this error.

EDIT:
My issue was in the .env file, I’ve written a ; rather than a :

Comment: This isn't my code, and i'm very new at coding, i'm searching a possible cause for this.

Comment: Is it possible that the problemi is in the sap certificate (online the site is https, on local http)

Comment: Is this form being posted through a button on the form or via AJAX? If it is through ajax you would need to pass through your token within the header section alongside the rest of the data.

Comment: It isn’t posted via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@method('POST')` this line and try because you don't need to mention `method="POST"`, you already mentioned method in form tag.
Welcome you in advance.

Comment: same error, even without the @method('POST')

Comment: then i think this issue is coming from your route check your web.php and controller, first check by adding  print_r("working"); exit; in top of your controller method and run the page to check its working or not if it works then its problem in code inside of controller method.

Comment: The problem was my .env file

Comment: @Tammapao01 what is the problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in the head of `app.blade.php` file

Comment: Already done it